# How to move text in lyx, preserving the information on changes

Tags: lyx, changes

I'm editing a manuscript with several people and we are using change-tracking intensively. Now I would like to change the order of two sections of the document without loosing all information about past changes within one of the sections.

All my copy/cut and paste trials result in loosing all the information on changes in the text that I wish to move.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks already!,

Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let go with a MWE:

> [image]

We wanted move "Some changed here" after "Normal text" without lost the traced changes. Steps to follow:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>May</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (deactivate change-tracking)
2. Add one-two fake sectioning levels to your document so that the chunk of text to move is now **alone** in a new section, subsection, or so.

> [image: Added a subsebtion]

3. If needed, make also a fake section  at the target point so that the target is just the end of some section or another level (It is not the case of the MWE because the target is the end of the last section).
4. Go the outline sidebar scheme with the table of contents, select the fake section to move it (using the buttons of the bottom) and left it after the target level.

> [image: moved subsection]

5. Remove the fake section/s and that is all.

> [image: Result]